# Mongoose save blocks cancels backend queries

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

My object has an array obj with 10k elements. After updating the array elements and calling `save` the server becomes `Temporary unresponsive`, hangs out and cancels all incoming request that I'm doing from another browser. I'm using `NestJs`

```
const foundParent = await this.parentModel
        .findOne({
              id: "some-id"
        })
        .exec();

for (const child of updatedChildren) {
      foundParent.children[+child.id] = child;
}

// hangs for a 60-70 seconds, and backend becomes unresponsive
await foundParent.save()
```

Why saving blocks the enitre backend ? And what are the correct approaches to the server to stay available ?

Comment: Poor modeling. Why would you want an array with 10k elements, all materialized, sent over the wire, and in memory? Just use another collection for the children and put an index on the parentId.

Comment: 3rd party provider returns the updated collection that needs to be replaced/partially updated

Comment: But I'm interested why the whole server is affected by waiting for the collection to be saved. Is it 1 thread for all clients ?

Comment: Yes. NodeJS is single thread. There is the event loop for async/await but other than that only 1 thread. And if that 1 thread is busy sending 10k array elements to the database, it may hang.

Comment: So if 2 users use the website simultaneously and a  3rd one comes along, he won't be able to use it. I would be happy if you answer me 2 brief questions. 
`1)` Above this code I'm awaiting a lambda function (whicl also takes some time, but the server is not hanging, does it just wait and redeive other requests while the computing power is offloaded to the Lambda ?). and `2)` Can we keep the server available if we offset this database writing to some other 3rd party server (for example the Lambda itself writting to Mongo ? )